# Remove bootstarp tooltip attributes using javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I have some html elements on which I have written js to add and remove bootstrap tooltip attributes where mouseover add attribute and mouseleave removes the attributes but for some reason tooltip is added but not removed

mouseover add attribute and mouseleave removes the attributes

```js
'use strict'

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
// get element font
    const getfont = (element, property) => {
        return window
            .getComputedStyle(element, null)
            .getPropertyValue(property)
    }
  // get element id
    const getId = (obj) => {
        return obj.id
    }
  // add remove tooltip
    const addTooltip = (element) => {
        element.setAttribute("data-bs-toggle", "tooltip")
        element.setAttribute("data-bs-placement", "bottom")
        element.setAttribute("data-bs-title", "Tooltip on top")
        new bootstrap.Tooltip(element)
        console.log(`Tooltip added`)

        // Remove the tooltip when the mouse leaves the element
        element.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
            const element = event.target

            element.removeAttribute("data-bs-toggle");
            element.removeAttribute("data-bs-placement");
            element.removeAttribute("data-bs-title");
            
            new bootstrap.Tooltip(element);
            /* const element = event.target
            const tooltip = bootstrap.Tooltip.getInstance(element); */
            // tooltip.dispose() // --> not working
            console.log(`Removed`)

        })
    }

// event listener
    addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
        console.log(getId(event.target));
    })

    addEventListener("mouseover", (event) => {
        //console.log(getfont(getId(event.target), "font-family")) // problem with this is I am passig id  instead of element

        const element = event.target
        const id = getId(element)
        if (id) {
            addTooltip(element)
            //console.log(getfont(element, "font-family"))
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is the manner in which tooltips are being managed. Upon a `mouseover` event, a new tooltip instance is initialized every time, without a direct command to show it. This leads to the repeated creation of tooltip instances for the same element. Conversely, during the `mouseleave` event, instead of disposing of the existing tooltip instance, the code is trying to create another tooltip.

Here is the corrected code that shows the tooltip after initialization with `tooltipInstance.show()`. During the `mouseleave` event, it retrieves the existing tooltip instance and properly disposes of it, ensuring that the tooltip is not only hidden but removed entirely.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const addTooltip = (element) => {
    element.setAttribute('data-bs-toggle', 'tooltip');
    element.setAttribute('data-bs-placement', 'bottom');
    element.setAttribute('data-bs-title', 'Tooltip on top');

    const tooltipInstance = new bootstrap.Tooltip(element);
    tooltipInstance.show();
    console.log(`Tooltip added`);

    element.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) => {
      const element = event.target;

      const tooltip = bootstrap.Tooltip.getInstance(element);
      if (tooltip) {
        tooltip.dispose();
      }
      console.log('Removed');
    });
  };

  document.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
    const element = event.target;
    const id = element.id;
    if (id) {
      addTooltip(element);
    }
  });
});
```

And here is a quick copy/paste example so that you can try it out on your PC and debug further if necessary:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tooltip Test</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container mt-5">
  <button id="btn-test" class="btn btn-primary">Hover over me!</button>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const addTooltip = (element) => {
    element.setAttribute('data-bs-toggle', 'tooltip');
    element.setAttribute('data-bs-placement', 'bottom');
    element.setAttribute('data-bs-title', 'Tooltip on top');

    const tooltipInstance = new bootstrap.Tooltip(element);
    tooltipInstance.show();
    console.log(`Tooltip added`);

    element.addEventListener('mouseleave', (event) => {
      const element = event.target;

      const tooltip = bootstrap.Tooltip.getInstance(element);
      if (tooltip) {
        tooltip.dispose();
      }
      console.log('Removed');
    });
  };

  document.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
    const element = event.target;
    const id = element.id;
    if (id) {
      addTooltip(element);
    }
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @jameshibbard my issues have been solved and your solution is working as I was expecting! However, it would be really helpful if you suggest some js code writing tips to write more effective code.

Comment: Glad to help. Re. writing better code, I would recommend: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS